# how to place content to the right of the fixed img with css 100% height (no width given)

Tags: css

How to place content to the right of the fixed img with css 100% height (no width given)

Image is fixed positioned to the left. And I want the content to go to the right. I don't know the width of the image as it depends on the 100% height. Here is the code: pastie.org/830531

SORRY: (CSS) POSITION: FIXED!!

Comment: You should elaborate on the question. What is a static img? is the image inside something? have you tried float?

Comment: Ok. Image is statically positioned to the left. And I want the content to go to the right. I don't know the width of the image as it depends on the 100% height.
Here is the code: http://pastie.org/830531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you're trying to do and what your "content" is, but you could try this:

```
<img src="URL" align="left" />your content here
```

This will make "your content" (text) appear to the right of the image.

You could also put the img in a DIV and make that float, or you could use a table, put the img in a TD and whatever your content is in a TD next to the image ...

I guess you'll have to you specify your question (or post example code) to get a better answer :)